# Create dbf table from C # - Problems with DateTime field

Tags: c#, date, datetime, visual-foxpro, dbf

I am trying to create a dbf table from a query to the database, made from a program written in C #.

I have followed the following thread:
[Create .DBF file from SQL table records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578233/create-dbf-file-from-sql-table-records/32696552)

For this the project has included another one of these, called DbfLibrary. In an example reduced to my problem, I do the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fhaltaColumn = DbfFieldDescriptors.GetDateTimeField("fhalta");

        var columns = new List<DbfFieldDescriptor>() {fhaltaColumn};

        Func<MyClass, object> mapfhalta = myClass => myClass.fhalta;

        var mapping = new List<Func<MyClass, object>>() { mapfhalta };

        List<MyClass> values = new List<MyClass>();

        values.Add(new MyClass()
        {
            fhalta = DateTime.Now
         });

        string fileName = "C:\\temp\\Archivo.dbf";
        DbfFileFormat.Write(@fileName, values, mapping, columns, Encoding.Default);
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public DateTime fhalta { get; set; }
    }
```

The result is a dbf file, with a field named fhalta, but the value is "/ /:: AM" and not DateTime.Now as I need.

How do I pass a datetime value correctly?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Specify the type in the parameter : new OleDbParameter( "parmDetails", OleDbType.Date)

Comment: I do not understand. Why an OleDbParameter?

Comment: The link you posted has examples of oldbeparameters.  You did not post the code with your query that should contain the parameters.

Comment: Actually, the method I am using and with which I cannot pass the DateTime type data correctly is "The Second Write Method".

Comment: You need to write to database using parameters.  The driver (similar to excel general formatting) is guessing at the type when you do not use a parameter.  So the drive may thing you are writing a number database instead of a date and changing the value.