# Create dbf file from C # - DateTime field

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, dbf

I used [this library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578233/create-dbf-file-from-sql-table-records/32696552) in my project. Library so very good, but i have some problems with format DateTime.
I create method in static class DbfFieldDescriptors for Date format

```
public static DbfFieldDescriptor GetDateField(string fieldName, byte length = 8)
{
  return new DbfFieldDescriptor(fieldName, 'D', length, (byte) 0);
}
```

and i trying map field in my file:

```
var dt = DbfFieldDescriptors.GetDateField("dt", 8);
Func<ExportDBF, object> dtMap = exportDbf => exportDbf.dt.Date.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
```

and this is not working, i.e. this is not write to file, field is empty

Has anyone encountered such a problem?
Can you help me with this?)
I would be very grateful!

Thank you!

full code for writing to file (in method GetExportDbf() i'm retrieve data from db):

```
var list = GetExportDbf(dateStart, dateEnd, accId);
var ndoc = DbfFieldDescriptors.GetStringField("ndoc", 10);
var dt = DbfFieldDescriptors.GetDateField("dt", 8);

var columns = new List<DbfFieldDescriptor>() 
{
   ndoc, dt
}; 

Func<ExportDBF, object> ndocMap = exportDbf => exportDbf.ndoc;
Func<ExportDBF, object> dtMap = exportDbf => exportDbf.dt.Date.ToString("yy-MM-dd");

var mapping = new List<Func<ExportDBF, object>>()
{
   ndocMap, dtMap
};

var result = DbfFileFormat.GetByteArray(list, mapping, columns, Encoding.Default);
return result;
```

Comment: Can you please share the full code for writing to your file?

Comment: @AmanB i'm edit post, adding full code. Thank You